# Cumulative sums over run lengths. Can this loop be vectorized?

Tags: r, vectorization, plyr, data.table

I have a data frame on which I calculate a run length encoding for a specific column. The values of the column, `dir`, are either -1, 0, or 1.

`dir.rle <- rle(df$dir)`

I then take the run lengths and compute segmented cumulative sums across another column in the data frame. I'm using a for loop, but I feel like there should be a way to do this more intelligently.

```
ndx <- 1
for(i in 1:length(dir.rle$lengths)) {
    l <- dir.rle$lengths[i] - 1
    s <- ndx
    e <- ndx+l
    tmp[s:e,]$cumval <- cumsum(df[s:e,]$val)
    ndx <- e + 1
}
```

The run lengths of `dir` define the start, `s`, and end, `e`, for each run. The above code works but it does not feel like idiomatic R code. I feel as if there should be another way to do it without the loop.

Comment: can you provide some example data? That will help.

Comment: If I misunderstood the structure of your data frame, let me know. You could update your question with the output of `dput(yourDataHere)`. If it's too large, use `subset()` or `head()` to make the example an appropriate size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be broken down into a two step problem. First, if we create an indexing column based off of the `rle`, then we can use that to group by and run the `cumsum`. The group by can then be performed by any number of aggregation techniques. I'll show two options, one using `data.table` and the other using `plyr`.

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
#data.table is the same thing as a data.frame for most purposes
#Fake data
dat <- data.table(dir = sample(-1:1, 20, TRUE), value = rnorm(20))
dir.rle <- rle(dat$dir)
#Compute an indexing column to group by
dat <- transform(dat, indexer = rep(1:length(dir.rle$lengths), dir.rle$lengths))


#What does the indexer column look like?
> head(dat)
     dir      value indexer
[1,]   1  0.5045807       1
[2,]   0  0.2660617       2
[3,]   1  1.0369641       3
[4,]   1 -0.4514342       3
[5,]  -1 -0.3968631       4
[6,]  -1 -2.1517093       4


#data.table approach
dat[, cumsum(value), by = indexer]

#plyr approach
ddply(dat, "indexer", summarize, V1 = cumsum(value))
```

Comment: Any incidcation of the speed difference between plyr and data.table?

Comment: Some shameless selfpromotion :). On my blog I posted a post that compares ave, ddply and data.table: http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/

Comment: @paul - my intuition seems to bear out your blog post. Data.table has been the quickest by many magnitudes in most cases when N becomes large. I'm more comfortable with plyr, but have been refactoring the bottlenecks lately.

Comment: Hadley Wickham (plyr author) responded to the code example in my post by saying that a new version of plyr would use speed enhancements like data.table. So maybe not to long from now the speed difference is going to be solved :).

Answer (score 4):

Both Spacedman & Chase make the key point that a grouping variable simplifies everything (and Chase lays out two nice ways to proceed from there).

I'll just throw in an alternative approach to forming that grouping variable. It doesn't use `rle` and, at least to me, feels more intuitive. Basically, at each point where `diff()` detects a change in value, the `cumsum` that will form your grouping variable is incremented by one:

```
df$group <- c(0, cumsum(!(diff(df$dir)==0)))

# Or, equivalently
df$group <- c(0, cumsum(as.logical(diff(df$dir))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a 'group' column to the data frame. Something like:

```
df=data.frame(z=rnorm(100)) # dummy data
df$dir = sign(df$z) # dummy +/- 1
rl = rle(df$dir)
df$group = rep(1:length(rl$lengths),times=rl$lengths)
```

then use tapply to sum within groups:

```
tapply(df$z,df$group,sum)
```

Comment: Good, except I _think_ the OP wanted cumulative sums that start over within each group (rather than the groupwise totals).

Comment: which is why we like reproducible examples in questions :) In truth he was pretty close.

Comment: Hallelujah, brother!  I've also wished for a feature that ran `paste([r], title_of_question)` through StackOverflow's search engine, and returned results before offering the "Submit" button. That would be esp useful for thinning out questions involving `"digits"`, `"round*`, and `"NA"`! (Not a complaint about the current question, which was interesting and showed plenty of thought prior to posting).